# Exporting Caret Resamples Results Summary to dataframe/csv

Tags: r, r-caret

I have run several train objects and collected the resampling results via the resamples() function in caret.  However, I would like to export those results to a data frame or ideally to a csv directly.  Is there any simple way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is about a million years old, but I had the exact same problem and in case someone else runs into this problem, you have to write it to a data frame first:

```
resamples <-data.frame(pls_model$resample)
```

You can then export it as a csv

```
write.csv(resamples, file = "Your_FileName.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `write.csv()` function

```
write.csv(data,file="Your_FileName.csv",row.names=F)
```

I prefer to remove the rownames from the CSV, but whatever you prefer

Comment: Unfortunately, the summary.resamples does not directly convert to a data frame.  Using the write.csv command, it throws the following error:   `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""summary.resamples"" to a data.frame`

Comment: could you add some more information about your dataset please. maybe use `str(data)`. If you've run the summary function on something you might have to extract specific elements such as `summary.resamples$coef` to get the results you want

Comment: Try `perf <- summary(resamples(x))`, then look at `str(perf)`, e.g. then get values using `perf$values` or Rsq using `perf$statistics$Rsquared`